# Visual Studio 2019 with C++ has been installed but CMake can't find it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, environment-variables, dlib

Visual Studio 2019 has been installed in my windows. I have coded c++ with it, and it doesn't have any problem with the compiler.
The compiler, `cl.exe`, exists in this directory:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x64`

When I wanted to install dlib using pip, CMake couldn't compile it.

```sh
pip install dlib                                                                                               ─╯
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.22.1.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ali entezari\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y4nrjyij\\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ali entezari\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y4nrjyij\\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\ali entezari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-cc19gyz4'
       cwd: C:\Users\ali entezari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y4nrjyij\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\
  Complete output (58 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\ali entezari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y4nrjyij\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\ali entezari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y4nrjyij\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\ali entezari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y4nrjyij\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\ali entezari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y4nrjyij\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
      setup(
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ali entezari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y4nrjyij\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\setup.py", line 134, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\ali entezari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y4nrjyij\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "D:\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\ali entezari\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y4nrjyij\\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\ali entezari\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y4nrjyij\\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=D:\\Anaconda\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\ali entezari\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y4nrjyij\\dlib_9dee571796eb4938989dad25a6107bfa\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
```

I've checked my environment variable path; `VS2019INSTALLDIR` was there.

| VS2019INSTALLDIR | C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community |
| --- | --- |

I had this problem with compiling Mozilla Firefox before, and I couldn't solve it. I will be appreciated if anyone could help me to get rid of this problem. *Sorry for English, I'm not a native speaker :).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was probably related to the plugins and extensions you have installed. My issue was not resolved until I reinstalled Visual Studio. Try to install it again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I installed Dlib on WSL, but I couldn't figure it out on Windows. I have many plugins installed on my visual studio, and it isn't easy to install them again. Is there any way to detect which plugin has corrupted it and prevent reinstalling visual studio?

Comment: Finally, I had to reinstall it, but maybe you can do it by disabling these Visual Studio plug-ins one by one. I hope it will be fixed and you will not have to install it again.